# Выделение определенных букв в слове при выводе

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как можно сделать так чтобы при выводе найденных в слове буквы, (po и ti) сложить обратно их в слово position но найденные буквы  выделить.

```
w =["position"]
l =["po","ow","ti","ht"]

def function(word,letter):
    assert type(word)== str and type(letter)== str
    if letter in word:
        print(letter) # Найдены  po, ti  
    return None

for word in w:
    for letter in l:
        function(word,letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Меняйте сразу

```
for word in w:
    for letter in l:
        word = word.replace(letter, '<b>'+letter+'</b>')
    print(word)
```

Comment: position po
<b>po</b>sition ow
<b>po</b>sition ti
<b>po</b>si<b>ti</b>on ht
<b>po</b>si<b>ti</b>on # что это даст?

Comment: https://eval.in/928361

Comment: Объявните пожалуйста более подробно ваш метод я немогу понять его смысл.

Comment: Вот правда, совсем не понимаю, что тут можно объяснить - *найденные буквы выделить* - я для примера выделил `<b></b>`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выделить жирным красным шрифтом части в строке, соответствующие заданному регулярному выражению, [можно `re.sub()` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
def highlighted(pattern, line):
    return pattern.sub(r'{BOLD}{RED}\1{RESET}'.format(**globals()), line)
```

Чтобы найти сочетания букв из вопроса, можно использовать `(po|ow|ti|ht)` регулярное выражение. Чтобы из произвольного списка сочетаний букв `parts` получить `pattern`:

```
import re

# match any part, longest first
pattern = re.compile('({})'.format(
    '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(parts, key=len, reverse=True)))))
```

При выводе строки в терминал, `BOLD` и `RED` могут содержать [последовательности управляющих символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI), чтобы поменять цвет, насыщенность шрифта:

```
import curses

curses.setupterm()
BOLD = curses.tigetstr('bold')
RED = curses.tparm(curses.tigetstr("setaf"), curses.COLOR_RED)
RESET = curses.tigetstr('sgr0')
```

К примеру, чтобы выделить слово `bold` жирным шрифтом в терминале:

```
RESET = '\033[0m'
BOLD =  '\033[1m'
print(f'{BOLD}bold{RESET}default')
```

Собирая всё вместе, можно реализовать [highlight утилиту](https://gist.github.com/zed/816ea46bbd5bf17cec730bc951bb38dc) — аналог `grep -Ff` команды:

[image: terminal session]